# How different is "Skype Connect" from "Skype for Asterisk"

Tags: gateway, sip, skype

We already use "Skype for Asterisk" channels to connect Skype to Asterisk PBX. Skype has a new offering called "Skype Connect" (or formerly "Skype for SIP"). What are the differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype for Asterisk is done using the Skype protocol and is sold/produced by Digium (Asterisk)

Skype for SIP is done using SIP and is simply a SIP channel sold to you by Skype

Answer (score 1):

i prefer Skype2SIP.no-ip.org

they provide an online free Skype to SIP gateway
it intergates with most VOIP PBX and working with any SIP client